# What use does syncManager make of numAuthExceptions

Tags: android

What does the SyncManager do with

syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions

Documentation seams to be lacking, although I have seen that numIoExceptions>0 is a softError, while numAuthExceptions>0 is a hardError?

Background:
In a syncAdpeter if I

```
syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++;
```

The syncAdapters retry mechanism operates.

If however I catch an authExecption, renew the auth token and do the following there are no retries

```
syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
```

Thats no retries, not just no successful retries. Only that one line is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation it says that "Hard errors are not retried". 
So, in the docs **numAuthExceptions** is a hard error. Because there is no point in trying to get to the server with wrong creds.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncResult.html#hasHardError()

**numIoExceptions** on the other hand is explicitly mentioned as a soft error.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncStats.html